# AIX firewall accept established connection

Tags: firewall, aix

I'm trying to configure a firewall for AIX to accept incoming connections on ports 22 and 443 and deny everything else. All is ok; the server accepts connections only on 22 and 443, but after that I also need to accept all outgoing connections -- ssh and telnet, for example.
So I started with

```
genfilt -v 4 -a P -s 0.0.0.0 -m 0.0.0.0 -d x.x.x.x -M 255.255.255.255 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O eq -P 22 -w I -i all
genfilt -v 4 -a P -s 0.0.0.0 -m 0.0.0.0 -d x.x.x.x -M 255.255.255.255 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O eq -P 443 -w I -i all
genfilt -v 4 -a D -s 0.0.0.0 -m 0.0.0.0 -d x.x.x.x -M 255.255.255.255 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O any -P 0 -w I -i all
```

Afterwards, I had to accept outgoing connections, so I introduced another rule:

```
genfilt -v 4 -a P -s 0.0.0.0 -m 0.0.0.0 -d x.x.x.x -M 255.255.255.255 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O eq -P 22 -w I -i all
genfilt -v 4 -a P -s 0.0.0.0 -m 0.0.0.0 -d x.x.x.x -M 255.255.255.255 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O eq -P 443 -w I -i all
**genfilt -v 4 -a P -s x.x.x.x -m 255.255.255.255 -d 0.0.0.0 -M 0.0.0.0 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O any -P 0 -r L -w O -i all**
genfilt -v 4 -a D -s 0.0.0.0 -m 0.0.0.0 -d x.x.x.x -M 255.255.255.255 -c tcp -o any -p 0 -O any -P 0 -w I -i all
```

After I use the new rule, server starts accepting all connections again.
I'm sure the new rule is definitely wrong, but I've never done an AIX firewall before.
Does anyone have any knowledge about this?

Comment: You don't mention which AIX release that is with? For your particular permit rules for port 22 and 443, a few comments: 1) you only allow TCP protocol 2) you allow any source port 3) you allow only incoming packages for that port, what about outgoing packages for that port? 4) I'm not sure whether `-O eq -P 22` is effectively the same as `-P 22` to specify the destination port as you don't specify any other rule for that port. 5) you should configure syslog to get some more verbose logging regarding your rules, see e.g. http://unixadmin.free.fr/?p=429